# numba - guvectorize barely faster than jit

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I was trying to parallellize a Monte Carlo simulation that operates on many independent datasets. I found out that numba's parallel guvectorize implementation was barely 30-40% faster than the numba jit implementation.

I found these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101699/numba-guvectorize-is-very-slow-compared-to-jit), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350689/numba-guvectorize-target-parallel-slower-than-target-cpu)) comparable topics on Stackoverflow, but they do not really answer my question. In the first case, the implementation is slowed down by a fall back to object mode and in the second case the original poster did not properly use guvectorize - none of these problems apply to my code.

To make sure there was no problem with my code, I created this very simple piece of code to compare jit to guvectorize:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, guvectorize

#both functions take an (m x n) array as input, compute the row sum, and return the row sums in a (m x 1) array

@guvectorize(["void(float64[:], float64[:])"], "(n) -> ()", target="parallel", nopython=True)
def row_sum_gu(input, output) :
    output[0] = np.sum(input)

@jit(nopython=True)
def row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array) :
    m, n = input_array.shape
    for i in range(m) :
        output_array[i] = np.sum(input_array[i,:])

rows = int(64) #broadcasting (= supposed parallellization) dimension for guvectorize
columns = int(1e6)
input_array = np.ones((rows, columns))
output_array = np.zeros((rows))
output_array2 = np.zeros((rows))

#the first run includes the compile time
row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array)
row_sum_gu(input_array, output_array2)

#run each function 100 times and record the time
print("jit time:", timeit.timeit("row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array)", "from __main__ import row_sum_jit, input_array, output_array", number=100))
print("guvectorize time:", timeit.timeit("row_sum_gu(input_array, output_array2)", "from __main__ import row_sum_gu, input_array, output_array2", number=100))
```

This gives me the following output (the times do vary a bit):

```
jit time: 12.04114792868495
guvectorize time: 5.415564753115177
```

Thus again, the parallel code is barely two times faster (only when the number of rows is an integer multiple of the number of CPU cores, otherwise the performance advantage diminishes) even though it utilizes all cpu cores and the jit code only uses one (verified using htop).

I am running this on a machine with 4x AMD Opteron 6380 CPU (so 64 cores in total), 256 GB of RAM and Red Hat 4.4.7-1 OS.
I use Anaconda 4.2.0 with Python 3.5.2 and Numba 0.26.0.

How can I further improve the parallel performance or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: For reference, I got times of 12s and 3.8s on a 2012 Macbook Air 1.6 GHz.  So despite your machine being "better" your JIT time is the same as mine and your guvectorize time is worse.

Comment: You might also want to check your two functions using some random data. They don't produce the same results.

Comment: @JoshAdel I tested using the following:  `input_array = np.random.rand(rows, columns)`  and `np.array_equal(output_array, output_array2)` returns True

Comment: @JohnZwinck I ran the code on different machines, both slower and faster and the guvectorize speedup was bigger on the slower machines, so I suspect that MSeifert's comment below is spot on.

Comment: @DriesVanLaethem you're right. Not sure what I did in my tests originally, but now they agree. My apologies

Comment: @JoshAdel No problem, I agree that it's a good idea to test this kind of thing also with random numbers instead of only ones.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because `np.sum` is too simple. Processing an array with sum is not only limited by CPU but also by the **"memory access" time**. So throwing more cores at it doesn't make *much* of a difference (of course that depends on how fast the memory access in relation to your CPU is).

Just for vizualisation `np.sum` is something like this (ignoring any parameter other than the `data`):

```
def sum(data):
    sum_ = 0.
    data = data.ravel()
    for i in data.size:
        item = data[i]   # memory access (I/O bound)
        sum_ += item     # addition      (CPU bound)
    return sum
```

So if most of the time is spent accessing the memory you won't see any real speedups if you parallize it. However if the CPU bound task is the bottleneck then using more cores will speedup your code significantly.

For example if you include some slower operations than addition you'll see a bigger improvement:

```
from math import sqrt
from numba import njit, jit, guvectorize
import timeit
import numpy as np

@njit
def square_sum(arr):
    a = 0.
    for i in range(arr.size):
        a = sqrt(a**2 + arr[i]**2)  # sqrt and square are cpu-intensive!
    return a

@guvectorize(["void(float64[:], float64[:])"], "(n) -> ()", target="parallel", nopython=True)
def row_sum_gu(input, output) :
    output[0] = square_sum(input)

@jit(nopython=True)
def row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array) :
    m, n = input_array.shape
    for i in range(m) :
        output_array[i] = square_sum(input_array[i,:])
    return output_array
```

I used [IPythons `timeit`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) here but it should be equivalent:

```
rows = int(64)
columns = int(1e6)

input_array = np.random.random((rows, columns))
output_array = np.zeros((rows))

# Warmup an check that they are equal 
np.testing.assert_equal(row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array), row_sum_gu(input_array, output_array2))
%timeit row_sum_jit(input_array, output_array.copy())  # 10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
%timeit row_sum_gu(input_array, output_array.copy())   # 10 loops, best of 3: 35.7 ms per loop
```

I'm only using 4 cores so that's pretty close to the limit of possible speedup!

Just remember that parallel computation can only significantly speedup your calculation **if the job is limited by the CPU**.

Comment: It's still surprising to me that OP's "4x AMD Opteron 6380" machine performs no better than my 2012 Macbook Air which surely has a worse memory subsystem (right?).

Comment: The machine I tested on has a Supermicro H8QG6-F motherboard with 16 x 16GB DDR3-1600 registered RAM. No idea if this setup is slower or faster than a Macbook Air's memory subsystem .

Comment: @MSeifert Thank you for the clear and elaborate explanation. I am restructuring my datasets and code to limit the number of times the memory is accessed.